# How to display an alert from push notification fcm

Tags: android, push-notification

I have the code below in the firebase routines. When a notification is received how do I display the notification message or data as an alert? My php code on my server successfully pushes messages to the android device by id and a sound is heard when the message is received, but I would like to display an alert or transfer to a fragment (I prefer the alert).

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService
{
    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMessService";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage)
    {
        commonfunc.myprint("#####_____MyFirebaseMessService_from 1 : " + remoteMessage.getFrom());


        if(remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0)
        {
            commonfunc.myprint("MyFirebaseMessService_getdata 2 : " + remoteMessage.getData());
            Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
            String value1 = data.get("dtitle");
            String value2 = data.get("dbody");
            commonfunc.myprint("MyFirebaseMessService_getdata 2 : " + value1 + " " + value2);
            sendNotification(remoteMessage.getData().toString());
        }
        if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null)
        {
            commonfunc.myprint("MyFirebaseMessService_getNot 3 body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            commonfunc.myprint("MyFirebaseMessService_getNot 3 title: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle());

            sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle());

            /*
            final String mMessage = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
            Handler h = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
            h.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run()
                {
                    AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyFirebaseMessagingService.this).create();
                    alertDialog.setTitle("Message");
                    alertDialog.setMessage("Message follows: " + mMessage);
                    alertDialog.setButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEUTRAL, "OK",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    dialog.dismiss();
                                }
                            });
                    alertDialog.show();
                    return ;
                }
            });
            */

        }
    }

    private void sendNotification(String body)
    {
        commonfunc.myprint("MyFirebaseMessService_sendNotification 4a sound ");

        Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        Uri notificationSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notifiBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setContentTitle("Firebase Cloud Messaging")
                .setContentText(body)
                .setSound(notificationSound)
                .setSmallIcon(life.poa.webcastman.poa1.R.drawable.common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0,notifiBuilder.build());

        commonfunc.myprint("MyFirebaseMessService_sendNotification 4b sound");
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "____MyFirebaseMessagingService " + body, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

}
```

Comment: Are you getting data inside onMessageReceived?

Comment: Yes, below is my php -and- I get both notification and data in the firebase routine    and write them to the log         $json_array = [
"notification" => [
"title" => "nTEST",
"sound" => "default",
"body" => "nollardata"
],
"data" => [
"dtitle" => "dTEST",
"sound" => "default",
"dbody" => "dollardata"
],
"to" => $target,
"priority" => "high"
];
$body = json_encode($json_array);

Comment: Does your notification shows the data?

Comment: plus I get in my android logV/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 1
I/System.out: myprint:#####_____MyFirebaseMessService_from 1 : xxxxxxxxxxxxx
I/System.out: myprint:MyFirebaseMessService_getdata 2 : {dtitle=dTEST, dbody=dollardata, sound=default}
I/System.out: myprint:MyFirebaseMessService_getdata 2 : dTEST dollardata
etc

Comment: I shows it in my android studio log and on the simulation at the top, but i guess can this be display as an alert dialog also?

Comment: So you are getting data in your service..you could create a local broadcast and sent it to a fragment and receive it  there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use a local Broadcast: Put this inside onMessageReceived:

```
 Intent intent = new Intent("myFunction");
                // add data
                intent.putExtra("value1", value1);
                intent.putExtra("value2", value2);
                LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
```

In you activity/Fragment:

```
private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // Extract data included in the Intent
            String t = intent.getStringExtra("value1");
            String t1 = intent.getStringExtra("value2");
            //alert data here
        }
    };


       @Override
        public void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this.getActivity()).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver,
                    new IntentFilter("myFunction"));
        }

        @Override
        public void onPause() {
            super.onPause();
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this.getActivity()).unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
        }
```

Comment: So basically put routine 1 in the on messagereceived function... and the private Broadcast at the botton of the firebase fragment and my function is a new fragment..correct?

Comment: @BillFoyer Nope..Only 1st part of code in onMessageReceived and private Broadcast in your fragment.. `myFunction` is just a name! You could give any name! It is not your fragment name

Comment: Thanks, Very good answer. I avoided the onPause part to let the notification shown in all the Apps screens

Comment: So I have to write it in each and every Activity or Fragment